# How to get the value of INSTALLDIR in wix

Tags: wix, wix3

Am copying files to INSTALLDIR using wix. And how do i get the path of copied file location. I want to use the value(path) of INSTALLDIR.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you please share your Wix code to understand where you are trying to get value to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Using [INSTALLDIR]. Directories with capital letters also act as property.

If you can use VbScript Custom Actions, then you can try this:
Msgbox Session.Property("INSTALLDIR")